How do you test GMail Addon Permission changes?
Recently, we found out that we don't need one set of permission scope for our gmail addon anymore. Because of this, I have deleted the said permission from my manifest and will be deleting it later in our google cloud listing.
My problem however is that I have no way to make the permissions-splash screen show whenever I do a test-deploy from the addon editor. The code works fine but I wanted to see the permissions splash screen to verify that the deleted permission is indeed removed from the list of permissions.
Is there a sandbox chrome web store where I can upload/publish my addon and test it from there? Is there a way for me to revoke permissions used by a test-deployed addon?
I hope the questions above make sense. And thank you in advance for your answers.
